# Is a problem in NP if it is decided by some non-deterministic, polynomial time turing machine?

Tags: complexity-theory, np

I am working trough the book "Introduction to the theory of computation", 3rd edition, by M. Sipser. On page 294, the book states:

> A problem is in NP iff it is decided by some non-deterministic,
>   polynomial time turing machine.

I get that it is decidable by some NDPTTM if the problem is in NP, the other way around I do not quite get.This is because I feel like all problems in $CoNP-NP$ can also be decided by some Non Deterministic polynomial time turing machine. I have the following solution in mind: Lets assume $P \neq NP \land NP \neq CoNP$. Take a problem $A \in NP - CoNP$. Now there is problem $\overline{A}$, which is in $CoNP$. Lets say NDTM $N$ decides $A$ in polynomial time. Now we modify $N$ by replacing every reject with accept and every accept with reject. We now have a polynomial NDTM $N'$ which decides $\overline{A}$ in poly time. According to the theorem proposed by the book, this should imply that $\overline{A}$ is in $NP$, but it is not.

Am I missing something here?

Edit:

So, I have seen the possible duplicates and I learned a lot: I see now that $N'$ does not necessarily decide $\overline{A}$. I Do still believe my question is subtly different, so here I go:

Take problem $B \in CoNP-NP$. There is a NDTM which decides $B$ in poly time, right? So, according to the theorem, $B$ should be in NP.

I firmly believe the book is correct, but does that mean that $B$ cannot be decided by any NDTM in poly time?

Comment: **NP** is, by definition, the things that can be decided by an NDTM in poly time. So, if you take a language such as $B$ which you've explicitly said is not in **NP**, then it cannot be decided by an NDTM in poly time.

Comment: So there is no NDTM which can decide a CoNPC problem in poly time? What does that mean for determining if a certain instance of a NPC problem is a no instance? Can that be done in poly time by some NDTM?

Comment: If **NP** and **coNP** are different, no NDTM cna decide **coNP**-complete problems in polynomial time. But we don't know if **NP** and **coNP** are different, which means that we don't know if there are NDTMs that decide the complement of **NP**-complete problems.